Unable to change a class Field in angular component using a Subject subscription
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthDataService } from '../Service/authDataService';
import { map } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../Model/userModel';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-success',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './success.component.html',
  styleUrl: './success.component.css',
})
export class SuccessComponent implements OnInit {
  authenticated = false;

  constructor(private authService: AuthDataService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.userSubject.subscribe((user) => {
      console.log(user);
      this.authenticated = !!user;
      console.log('In the body of subscribe');
      //true here
      console.log(this.authenticated);
    });
    //still false
    console.log('outside');
    console.log(this.authenticated);
  }

  check() {
    //false here to
    console.log(this.authenticated);
  }
}

I'm trying to emit a change in user object to all my components using a subscription... but it doesn't seem to change the Boolean value even after a change is emitted...

what is the type and the value of what is emitted by the userSubjet?

The code inside the subscribe is called asynchronous code which is different from synchronous code, async code happens at a later point of time, it waits for the event to happen, but the code below it will not wait for the subscribe to complete, so to handle this you need to move you logic that you want to happen after auth inside the subscribe
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.userSubject.subscribe((user) => {
      console.log(user);
      this.authenticated = !!user;
      console.log('In the body of subscribe');
      //asynchronous move all your logic inside here!
      console.log(this.authenticated);
    });
    // synchronous does not wait for subscribe to complete
    console.log('outside');
    console.log(this.authenticated);
  }


Thank you Mr Naren Murali... But is there any way I could change the value globally... I tried unsubscribing it from ngOnDestroy()

@MathewFrancis Try settting this value in a service property, ensure the service has providedIn: 'root' set and should not be added to any providers array, if you want to access the service property anywhere you can just do `get authenticated() {return this.service.authenticated; }

I Removed the Subject altogether and instead did this in the
service:-
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../Model/userModel';
import { Subject, tap } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthDataService {
  
  authenticated = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  testService() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  //LOG-IN posting basic auth to the backend

  postBasicAuthData(username: string, password: string) {
    console.log(username, password);

    const header = new HttpHeaders();

    const authHeader = header.set(
      'Authorization',
      'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ':' + password)
    );

    return this.http
      .get<any>('http://localhost:8080/login/LoginUser', {
        headers: authHeader,
        observe: 'response',
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .pipe(
        tap((responseData) => {
          if (responseData) this.authenticated = true;
        })
      );
  }

  //SIGN-UP sign up a new user

  newUserDetailsPost(
    username: string,
    password: string,
    age: number,
    email: string
  ) {
    console.log(username, password, age, email);

    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/Sign-up/signup-user', {
      name: username,
      password: password,
      age: age,
      email: email,
    });
  }
}

LoginComponent:-
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthDataService } from '../../Service/authDataService';
import { WrongInputDirective } from '../../Directive/wrong-input.directive';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { User } from '../../Model/userModel';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterLink, FormsModule, WrongInputDirective, CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css', '../login-signup.component.css'],
  // styleUrl: './login.component.css'
})
export class LoginComponent {
  formCondition = false;
  constructor(private authService: AuthDataService, private router: Router) {}

  onSubmit(formSettings: NgForm) {
    const formDataFields = formSettings.form.value;

    const username = formDataFields.username;
    const password = formDataFields.password;

    //   .subscribe({
    //     complete: () => { ... }, // completeHandler
    //     error: () => { ... },    // errorHandler
    //     next: () => { ... },     // nextHandler
    //     someOtherProperty: 42
    // });
    this.authService.postBasicAuthData(username, password).subscribe({
      next: (v) => {
        console.log(v);
        const user = <User>v.body;
        //console.log(user);
        //console.log(v.headers.get('Authorization'));
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(
          'Authorization',
          //If you are confident that the localStorage.getItem() call can never return null you can use the non-null (!) assertion operator to tell typescript that you know what you are doing:
          v.headers.get('Authorization')!
        );

        window.sessionStorage.setItem('userDetails', JSON.stringify(user!));
        console.log('Success');

        this.router.navigate(['welcome']);
      },
      error: (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        console.log('Error');
        this.formCondition = true;
      },
      complete: () => console.info('complete'),
    });
    // formSettings.reset();
  }

  resetInputStatus() {
    this.formCondition = false;
  }
}

I just want to clarify if this is an acceptable alternative
